# Finding the basis for Product Topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

$X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ is given the topology $T_X = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,c,d\}, \{c,d\}, X \}$ and $Y = \{1,2,3\}$ given the topology $T_Y = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,3\}, Y \}$.

Will a basis for the product topology on $X \times Y$ be:

$B_{X \times Y} = \{ \{a\} \times \{1\}, \{a\} \times \{1,3\}, \{a\} \times Y, \{c,d\} \times \{1\}, \{c,d\}\times \{1,3\}, \{c,d\}\times Y \}$

or

$B_{XxY} = \{ \{a\} \times \{1\}, \{a,c,d\} \times \{1\}, \{c,d\} \times\{1\}, \{a\} \times \{1,3\}, \{a,c,d\} \times \{1,3\}, \{c,d\} \times \{1,3\}, \{a\} \times Y, \{c,d\} \times Y, \{c,d\} \times Y \}$

and if so; why is $B_{XxY} = T_{XxY}$ and the union of $\{a\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ included in the basis?

Also, should the empty set be included in the basis?

Comment: A basis for a topology needs not contain $\emptyset$, because $\emptyset$ is the union of the empty subfamily anyways (in addition to being the union of the singleton of the empty set). However, keep in mind that any open set can be added to a basis, and you still obtain a basis.

Comment: It general if $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $X$ and $\mathcal C$ is a basis for $Y$ then the set $\{B\times C\mid B\in\mathcal B, C\in\mathcal C\}$ is a basis for $X\times Y$.

Comment: @MPW If $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $S$ then $\bigcup\mathcal B=S$. So if $S$ has indiscrete topology then $\mathcal B$ must contain $S$.

Comment: The first is not a basis of the topology because $\{1\}\times Y \not\subset X\times Y$ . The second is a basis, though it still would be if some of the sets were dropped. However, contrary to your claim, it is not $T_{X\times Y}$, which includes $\emptyset$ and $X \times Y$.

Comment: Thank you @PaulSinclair ! That really makes sense :)

Comment: I realize I made a typo for the first @PaulSinclair ... instead of {1}× it was supposed to be  {c,d}× (I fixed the typo now). Does that make the first one a complete basis? What I was thinking was that the terms containing  {a,c,d} in the second seemed unessecary.

Comment: I thought it was likely to be a typo, but didn't know what was supposed to be there. And yes, since $\{ \{a\}, \{c, d\}\}$ is a basis for $X$ and $\{ \{1\}, \{1, 3\}\}$ is a basis for $Y$, any collection of subsets of $X \times Y$ that (1) consists of products of opens sets of $X$ with open sets of $Y$ and (2) includes every product of sets from those two bases, will be a basis for the product topology on $X \times Y$. Both of your $B_{X\times Y}$ sets now meet these conditions.

Comment: And, just to be clear: For this particular example, it **may** be that the sets described above are the only basis sets for the product topology (I haven't examined it in detail). But in general this is false - even for finite products of finite topologies like here.  The product topology is *defined* using products of open sets, but there are other bases which include sets that are not products of open sets in $X, Y$. For example, the normal topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is the product topology of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, but the most common basis for it is open disks, not open rectangles.

Comment: Again @PaulSinclair thank you so much :)